# Filter Items Dynamically based on selected Input in R

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, filtering

I need to filter data and create a new column OutOfSpec based on dynamic input selected from a selectInput widget as follows:

mutate(OutOfSpec = ifelse(Assayperc < (AssaypercLL %in% input$assayCountry)| Assayperc > (AssaypercUL %in% input$assayCountry), BatchNumber, ""))

assayCountry is a selectInput of the ActiveIngredient column. So basically, I need this code to pick up the corresponding AssaypercLL and the AssaypercUL and compare to the Assayperc. If the Assayperc is outside the AssayperLL and AssaypercUL, then the BatchNumber is annotated to the created OutOfSpec column. Thank youIs the above right as I seem to be getting weird results which is opposite of the expected as all data is being labelled as out of specification.  Please assist.

The data is as follows:

```
structure(list(ï..ActiveIngredient = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Caridone", 
"Entepronone"), class = "factor"), Assay = c(94.9, 94.9, 94.9, 
94.9, 94.9, 94.9, 101.6, 101.6, 101.6, 101.6, 101.6, 101.6, 95, 
95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 100.2, 100.2, 100.2, 100.2, 100.2, 100.2, 
96.4, 96.4, 96.4, 96.4, 96.4, 96.4, 100.6, 100.6, 100.6, 100.6, 
100.6, 100.6, 93.7, 93.7, 93.7, 93.7, 93.7, 93.7, 101.8, 101.8, 
101.8, 101.8, 101.8, 101.8, 90.5, 90.5, 90.5, 90.5, 90.5, 90.5, 
101.4, 101.4, 101.4, 101.4, 101.4, 101.4, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 
91, 99.9, 99.9, 99.9, 99.9, 99.9, 99.9, 92.6, 92.6, 92.6, 92.6, 
92.6, 92.6, 93.5, 93.5, 93.5, 93.5, 93.5, 93.5, 94, 94, 94, 94, 
94, 94, 95.7, 95.7, 95.7, 95.7, 95.7, 95.7, 98.6), Assayperc = c(0.949, 
0.949, 0.949, 0.949, 0.949, 0.949, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 
1.016, 1.016, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1.002, 1.002, 
1.002, 1.002, 1.002, 1.002, 0.965, 0.965, 0.965, 0.965, 0.965, 
0.965, 1.006, 1.006, 1.006, 1.006, 1.006, 1.006, 0.937, 0.937, 
0.937, 0.937, 0.937, 0.937, 1.018, 1.018, 1.018, 1.018, 1.018, 
1.018, 0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 0.905, 1.014, 1.014, 
1.014, 1.014, 1.014, 1.014, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 
0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.926, 0.926, 0.926, 
0.926, 0.926, 0.926, 0.935, 0.935, 0.935, 0.935, 0.935, 0.935, 
0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.957, 0.957, 0.957, 0.957, 
0.957, 0.957, 0.986), AssayLL = c(90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 93L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 93L, 93L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 
93L, 93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 
93L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L
), AssaypercLL = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.93, 0.93, 
0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.93), AssayUL = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
107L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 107L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L), AssaypercUL = c(1.1, 1.1, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.1, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
1.07), BatchNumber = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("170722", 
"17095", "180301", "180702", "ACO36", "CUJ108004", "FN7001"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-97L))
```

Comment: What are you intending the term `Assayperc < (AssaypercLL %in% input$assayCountry)` to do?

Comment: fyi the pasted data has no AssaypercLL or BatchNumber, is it incomplete?

Comment: Thank you very much for your observation, much appreciated, i have resposted with new data.  I am intending to create a new column called "OutOfSpec" which will be labelled with the BatchNumber if the particular record is not within the specified limits,

Comment: `AssaypercLL` is a numeric value, presumably a percentage. Is `input$assayCountry` a vector of percentages? That term is testing to see if `AssaypercLL` is in the vector `input$assayCountry` and will output TRUE aka 1 if so, FALSE aka 0 if not. And then you're comparing that to `Assayperc`?

Comment: It would help if you could describe how the parts in your dynamic filter are supposed to work. It's hard to tell from the code what your intention is and why the output you're getting is "weird results."

Comment: Thank you Jon.  assayCountry is a selectInput of the ActiveIngredient column.  So basically, I need this code to pick up the corresponding AssaypercLL and the AssaypercUL   and compare to the Assayperc.  If the Assayperc is outside the AssayperLL and AssaypercUL, then the BatchNumber is annotated to the created OutOfSpec column.  Thank you

Comment: 1) Please edit your question so it contains the information people would need to answer it without reviewing the comment thread.  2) I still don't get it. So your selectInput might select an `ActiveIngredient` of "Caridone." What next? There are 43 corresponding rows with that ActiveIngredient, but none of them have an Assayperc that is either less than that row's AssaypercLL or higher than its AssaypercUL.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have edited as advised.  It might be that the specific data provided does not contain out of specification data, it is just a reprex from the main data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, much appreciated. Just removed int %in% in the code and its now working perfectly